# angular6 - ngx-editor icons do not appear on production

Tags: icons, angular6, production, ngx-editor

I am developing an angular6 app.
I am using ngx-editor.

The editor seems to work fine in localhost, but when I deploy it in firebase the icons don't appear at all.

[image]

[image]

What could be the reason? 
Please let me know if you need any more details.

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Font-Awesome style sheet is not getting deployed to the server. If you embed the following css in your component's CSS

> @import
>   url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

And set the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your @component decorator of `.ts` file, the icons should appear

> encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

Make sure you have the appropriate [angular-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) for your angular version
add/edit the following files:

angular-editor.module.ts

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

angular-editor.component.ts

```
import {FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {far} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import {fas} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

constructor(
   library: FaIconLibrary,
) {
  library.addIconPacks(fas, far);
}
```

angular-editor-toolbar.component.ts edit all icon tags.

to

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'icon-name']" >
```